# Antlr4: The type or namespace name 'XPathLexer' could not be found

Tags: antlr4, antlr4cs

I am trying to understand Antlr CS code on VS 2010 with `Antlr4.Runtime.net40-client` and  `Antlr4BuildTasks.net40` projects out of all .net framework versions.

The later is building fine but in case of first one I get `The type or namespace name 'XPathLexer' could not be found`. I believe it is because of `XPathLexer.g4` not working, hence lexer and parser are not created.

Also am I wrong to suppose that `Antlr4BuildTasks` job is to build the other?

I made unnecessarily small change in XPathlexer.g4 grammar to see if shows some file generation but it didn't.

Can someone guide me to set up .net framework v4 projects on Visual studio?

Comment: The project has a Gitter chat room where you can ask these questions and get answers more easily: https://gitter.im/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4cs